# Adding a number picker to each table view cell

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipickerview

I am very new to iOS development. Currently, I am trying to develop an iPad app for taking orders in a restaurant. The UI should be like this:http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ipad_menu_final.jpg As people suggested, it would be easier to start by creating a Master/Detail project as the basic structure. After going through a couple of tutorials, I know how to display detail contents when I select rows at master view. Now, my assumption is to add an UITableView to the detail view controller, and at each UITableView Cell, I want to add some text to describe the menu item and also an UIPickerView to let the user select the quantity of each item (like the pic in the above link).  Am I on the right track? How can I add an UITextField and UIPickerView to each UITableView cell programmatically? Are there any examples or tutorials teach me how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: okay nice but what you have to tried ??

Comment: That isn't a standard UIPickerView - you'll have to write your own custom one.

Comment: Ya UIPickerView isn't what you want I suspect. Two UIbuttons that interact with a quantity variable (per cell), one being the one with the quantity value being displayed on it, Is more along the lines. You need to look into creation a custom UITableViewCell which will contain your textfield, labels etc. A good example is answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014105/where-is-a-good-tutorial-for-making-a-custom-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - THE VIEW : Create a `UITableViewCell` subclass (ex: MyMenuItemCell), with the properties you need

- a `UIImageView` for the picture
- a `UILabel` for the price (with some `CALayer` `cornerRadius`, `backgroundColor`, and `borderColor` tweaking)
- another `UILabel` for the title describing the product
- another `UILabel` for the description
- a `UIButton` to get userAction, but handle that in another class, as this cell is the VIEW, and should hold no control logic, this is the `CONTROLLER`'s part.

2 - THE CONTROLLER

You `UIViewController` should implement `<UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate>`. (or it can directly be a `UITableViewController` subclass, which provides some generic benefits, like moving the tableView when a keyboard is displayed. If you choose this 2nd option, and create the viewController programmatically, be sure to use the `initWithStyle:` method)

3 - BIND VIEW with CONTROLLER

However you choose to enable 'quantity pick' :

- with some `UIStepper` (+ and - buttons) linked to a `UILabel`

or

- in some dedicated `UIPickerView` displayed in a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UIPopoverController`

(or any other design you see fit)

you should write the code that triggers this action handling IN your controller, when `UITableViewCell` are instantiated / reused, in `UITableViewDatasource` method providing cells instances :
`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`